# Get the answer from a table using data from other table

Tags: sql

How to get the answer to this question using SQL?

> What is the name of gatekeeper(s), who are at the gate of a mouse?

(the tables are not in the best format, but imagine that they have 3 columns and the row with "ID ..." is the headline)

the whole "gatekeeper" table

```
ID  gatekeeper  gate    
1   TE          4    
2   ER          1    
3   PU          2    
4   WD          3    
5   TR          5
```

the whole "gates" table

```
ID  animal  gate    
1   cat     3    
2   dog     1    
3   mouse   2
```

Is it like this?

```
SELECT gatekeeper
FROM gatekeeper
WHERE gate = (SELECT gate from gates where animal = mouse);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT gatekeeper.gatekeeper 
FROM gatekeeper 
JOIN gates on gates.gate = gatekeeper.gate AND gates.animal = 'mouse'
```

Comment: I just wanted to add one additional question.
How would the code change, if there was another table: 
Country animal
US       cat
UK       dog
IN       mouse  

And the question would be:
What is the name of gatekeeper(s), who is located in US? (it maybe does not really make sense, but my point is – how to write a code, if you need to connect data from three tables)

Comment: @user3702392: Just join the table on a different column. But maybe you should try reading some tutorials like the SQL-Tutorial on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Answer (score 1):

How do you define 'easy'? The easiest way should be the way you are most comfortable with. However, a subselect can really slow down the performance of a query. It's better to use joins, like this:

```
SELECT gk.gatekeeper
FROM gatekeeper AS gk
    JOIN gate AS g on g.gate = gk.gate
WHERE g.animal = 'mouse'
```